# VHDL: can't infer register for "c[0]" because its behavior does not match any supported register model

Tags: vhdl, counter

Hi I'm having problems with this one. this is supposed to be a counter that recives signals from two ports, a incriases it by one with a maximum of 30 and b decreases it by one with a maximum of 0, if the counter is at 30 the output should be x <= 0 and y <=1, otherwise x<=1 and y<=0. What am i doing wrong? Is it a good idea to use an integer for the cariable? This is my code, sorry if it looks dumb this is my first semester with VHDL

```
Library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity contador is
    port (a, b : in std_logic;
          x, y : out std_logic);

end entity;

architecture func of contador is

begin
    process(a,b)
        variable c : integer := 0;
    begin
        if rising_edge(a) then
            if c<31 then    
                c := c+1;
            end if;
        end if;
        if rising_edge(b) then
            if c>0 then
                c := c-1;
            end if;
        end if;

        if c = 30 then
            x <= '0';
            y <= '1';
        else
            x <= '1';
            y <= '0';
        end if;

    end process;

end func;
```

Error message:

Error (10821): HDL error at contador.vhd(22): can't infer register for "c[0]" because its behavior does not match any supported register model

Error (10821): HDL error at contador.vhd(22): can't infer register for "c[1]" because its behavior does not match any supported register model

.

.

.

Error (10821): HDL error at contador.vhd(22): can't infer register for "c[18]" because its behavior does not match any supported register model

Error (12153): Can't elaborate top-level user hierarchy

Error: Quartus II 64-Bit Analysis & Synthesis was unsuccessful. 20 errors, 4 warnings
    Error: Peak virtual memory: 4629 megabytes
    Error: Processing ended: Mon Jun 01 17:16:02 2020
    Error: Elapsed time: 00:00:02
    Error: Total CPU time (on all processors): 00:00:02
Error (293001): Quartus II Full Compilation was unsuccessful. 22 errors, 4 warnings

Comment: Your synthesis tool error message is telling you that c can't be mapped to hardware primitives because there are no registers with two clocks. Are a and b input from buttons? If so they'd need to be debounced. Without peering at some of the lecture and reading material preceding and the assignment itself (context) it's risky to tell you how to implement for course credit. Think single clock and a and b telling you when there's a counter event and direction. Please put your complete error message in the question body.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes is pretty much just a counter with '+' and '-' buttons and two LEDs, alaso it cannot go below or beyond its limits (0-30). This is just a "pre-assignment", is wortholess by itself so I assume I can implement it however I want, I guess we will have to connect a multiplexed 7-segment display in the graded lab but I don't know yet

Comment: Well you've made a good start. Probably best to go for a single clock and test the buttons on the rising edge of that clock. Take a look at our answers to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61630181/vhdl-button-debouncing-or-not-as-the-case-may-be/62067752#62067752) where the button inputs are synchronised and debounced before being tested.

Answer (score 0):

Well first you haven't explained what exactly your input signals are and how they behave, which is very important. 
Second, what you are basically doing is trying to implement a register with 2 clocks, in other words doing more than 1 clocked condition in a single process, the development tools usually don't like it and will warn you about it.

Also, you haven't specified the range of your variable.
Although most likely that the synthesis tool will ignore the unused bits,it is still good practice to exactly specify the range of your signals/variables. 
Like so:

```
variable c : integer range 0 to 32 := 0;
```

Your code can still be simulated or maybe even synthesized and i'm not sure why you are getting this error. You should put your exact error massage.

I think that most likely is that the device you are using in Quartus does not have the building block to support a 2 clocked input therefore you have the error that you are getting.

Try to create a separate process for each input, a and b, and then combine them with some logic.

Also, i made a small change in your code, try it and maybe it will help:

```
Library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity contador is
port (a, b : in std_logic;
      x, y : out std_logic);

end entity;

architecture func of contador is

 begin
  process(a,b)
      variable c : integer range 0 to 32 := 0;
  begin
    if rising_edge(a) then
        if c<31 then    
            c := c+1;
        end if;
    elsif rising_edge(b) then
        if c>0 then
            c := c-1;
        end if;
    end if;

    if c = 30 then
        x <= '0';
        y <= '1';
    else
        x <= '1';
        y <= '0';
    end if;

end process;

end func;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm "using" a FPGA Cyclone II. The ports 'a' and 'b' are just external buttons. I tried separating the procceses but the part of the code that generates the output no longer worked. do you know how could i make it work

Answer (score 0):

Some basic rules for processes

1. You can only have one clock in a process.
2. Don't mix clocked and unclocked processes.
3. You can't drive a signal from more than one process without causing problems.
4. Never use FPGA inputs as clocks.

So, create a clock inside your FPGA. Use it as your only clock.
Determine when a button has been pressed. Remember, it will be a slow, long input.
Create a counter.

Answer (score 0):

## Synchronise and Debounce

Since inputs `a` and `b` are asynchronous tactile buttons, they need to be synchronised to the clock and debounced, somthing like this:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Debounce is
    generic
    (
        CLOCK_PERIOD   : time := 20 ns;
        DEBOUNCE_PERIOD: time := 125 ms;  -- 1/8th second as a rule of thumb for a tactile button/switch.
        SYNC_BITS      : positive := 3    -- Number of bits in the synchronisation buffer (2 minimum).
    );
    port
    (
        clock : in std_logic;
        input : in std_logic;          -- Asynchronous and noisy input.
        output: out std_logic := '0';  -- Synchronised, debounced and filtered output.
        edge  : out std_logic := '0';  -- Goes high for 1 clock cycle on either edge of synchronised and debounced input.
        rise  : out std_logic := '0';  -- Goes high for 1 clock cycle on the rising edge of synchronised and debounced input.
        fall  : out std_logic := '0'   -- Goes high for 1 clock cycle on the falling edge of synchronised and debounced input.
    );
end entity;

architecture V1 of Debounce is

    constant SYNC_BUFFER_MSB: positive := SYNC_BITS - 1;
    signal sync_buffer: std_logic_vector(SYNC_BUFFER_MSB downto 0) := (others => '0');  -- N-bit synchronisation buffer (2 bits minimum).
    alias sync_input: std_logic is sync_buffer(SYNC_BUFFER_MSB);  -- The synchronised input is the MSB of the synchronisation buffer.

    constant MAX_COUNT: natural := DEBOUNCE_PERIOD / CLOCK_PERIOD;
    signal counter: natural range 0 to MAX_COUNT := 0;  -- Specify the range to reduce number of bits that are synthesised.

begin

    assert SYNC_BITS >= 2 report "Need a minimum of 2 bits in the synchronisation buffer.";

    process(clock)
        variable edge_internal: std_logic := '0';
        variable rise_internal: std_logic := '0';
        variable fall_internal: std_logic := '0';
    begin
        if rising_edge(clock) then
            -- Synchronise the asynchronous input.
            -- MSB of sync_buffer is the synchronised input.
            sync_buffer <= sync_buffer(SYNC_BUFFER_MSB - 1 downto 0) & input;

            counter <= 0;
            edge <= '0';  -- Goes high for 1 clock cycle on either edge.
            rise <= '0';  -- Goes high for 1 clock cycle on the rising edge.
            fall <= '0';  -- Goes high for 1 clock cycle on the falling edge.

            if counter = MAX_COUNT - 1 then  -- If successfully debounced, notify what happened, and reset the counter.
                output <= sync_input;
                edge <= edge_internal;  -- Goes high for 1 clock cycle on either edge.
                rise <= rise_internal;  -- Goes high for 1 clock cycle on the rising edge.
                fall <= fall_internal;  -- Goes high for 1 clock cycle on the falling edge.
            elsif sync_input /= output then
                counter <= counter + 1;
            end if;
        end if;

        -- Edge detection.
        edge_internal := sync_input xor output;
        rise_internal := sync_input and not output;
        fall_internal := not sync_input and output;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

## Contador

I've added a clock signal to `Contador` and rearranged your `if` statements to be active on its positive edge. Your output logic for `x` and `y` was fine, though I've added a generic parameter `MAX_COUNT` to make the code less error prone, more readable and maintainable. Both input buttons are debounced which I've renamed `btn_up` and `btn_dn`. I've also added a couple of LEDs for button feedback.

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Contador is
    generic
    (
        CLOCK_PERIOD   : time := 20 ns;
        DEBOUNCE_PERIOD: time := 125 ms;
        MAX_COUNT      : natural := 30
    );
    port
    (
        clock : in std_logic;
        btn_up: in std_logic;
        btn_dn: in std_logic;
        led_up: out std_logic;
        led_dn: out std_logic;
        x     : out std_logic;
        y     : out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture V1 of Contador is

    signal count_up: std_logic;
    signal count_dn: std_logic;

    component Debounce is
        generic
        (
            CLOCK_PERIOD   : time := 20 ns;
            DEBOUNCE_PERIOD: time := 125 ms
        );
        port
        (
            clock : in std_logic;
            input : in std_logic;
            output: out std_logic;
            rise  : out std_logic
        );
    end component;

begin

    DEBOUNCE_BTN_UP:
    Debounce
    generic map
    (
        CLOCK_PERIOD    => CLOCK_PERIOD,
        DEBOUNCE_PERIOD => DEBOUNCE_PERIOD
    )
    port map
    (
        clock  => clock,
        input  => btn_up,
        output => led_up,
        rise   => count_up  -- Goes high for 1 clock cycle on the rising edge of btn_up.
    );

    DEBOUNCE_BTN_DN:
    Debounce
    generic map
    (
        CLOCK_PERIOD    => CLOCK_PERIOD,
        DEBOUNCE_PERIOD => DEBOUNCE_PERIOD
    )
    port map
    (
        clock  => clock,
        input  => btn_dn,
        output => led_dn,
        rise   => count_dn  -- Goes high for 1 clock cycle on the rising edge of btn_dn.
    );

    process(clock)
        variable counter: natural range 0 to MAX_COUNT := 0;  -- Specify the range to reduce number of bits that are synthesised.
    begin
        if rising_edge(clock) then
            if count_up = '1' and counter < MAX_COUNT then
                counter := counter + 1;
            elsif count_dn = '1' and counter > 0 then
                counter := counter - 1;
            end if;
        end if;
        if counter = MAX_COUNT then
            x <= '0';
            y <= '1';
        else
            x <= '1';
            y <= '0';
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

## Test Bench

The test bench performs a series of button presses to show up and down counting, and what happens at the extremes of the count range.

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.math_real.all;

entity Contador_TB is
end;

architecture V1 of Contador_TB is

    constant CLOCK_PERIOD   : time := 50 ns;
    constant DEBOUNCE_PERIOD: time := 200 ns;

    signal halt_sys_clock: boolean := false;

    signal clock: std_logic := '0';
    signal btn_up: std_logic;
    signal btn_dn: std_logic;
    signal x: std_logic;
    signal y: std_logic;

    component Contador is
        generic
        (
            CLOCK_PERIOD   : time := 10 ns;
            DEBOUNCE_PERIOD: time := 125 ms
        );
        port
        (
            clock : in std_logic;
            btn_up: in std_logic;
            btn_dn: in std_logic;
            x     : out std_logic;
            y     : out std_logic
        );
    end component;

begin

    ClockGenerator:
    process
    begin
        while not halt_sys_clock loop
            clock <= not clock;
            wait for CLOCK_PERIOD / 2.0;
        end loop;
        wait;
    end process ClockGenerator;

    Stimulus:
    process
        constant NUM_NOISE_SAMPLES: positive := 10;
        constant SWITCH_TIME: time := 2 * DEBOUNCE_PERIOD;
        variable seed1: positive := 1;
        variable seed2: positive := 1;
        variable rrand: real;
        variable nrand: natural;

        -- Performs noisy transition of sig from current value to final value.
        procedure NoisyTransition(signal sig: out std_logic; final: std_logic) is
        begin
            for n in 1 to NUM_NOISE_SAMPLES loop
                uniform(seed1, seed2, rrand);
                nrand := natural(round(rrand));
                if nrand = 0 then
                    sig <= not final;
                else
                    sig <= final;
                end if;
                wait for CLOCK_PERIOD / 5.0;
            end loop;
            sig <= final;
            wait for SWITCH_TIME;
        end;

    begin
        btn_up <= '0';
        btn_dn <= '0';
        wait for 3 ns;

        --
        -- Up Button
        --

        -- Perform 10 noisy presses and releases.
        for n in 1 to 10 loop
            NoisyTransition(btn_up, '1');
            NoisyTransition(btn_up, '0');
        end loop;

        --
        -- Down Button
        --

        -- Perform 2 noisy presses and releases.
        for n in 1 to 2 loop
            NoisyTransition(btn_dn, '1');
            NoisyTransition(btn_dn, '0');
        end loop;

        --
        -- Up Button
        --

        -- Perform 27 noisy presses and releases.
        for n in 1 to 27 loop
            NoisyTransition(btn_up, '1');
            NoisyTransition(btn_up, '0');
        end loop;

        --
        -- Down Button
        --

        -- Perform 15 noisy presses and releases.
        for n in 1 to 15 loop
            NoisyTransition(btn_dn, '1');
            NoisyTransition(btn_dn, '0');
        end loop;

        --
        -- Up Button
        --

        -- Perform 2 noisy presses and releases.
        for n in 1 to 2 loop
            NoisyTransition(btn_up, '1');
            NoisyTransition(btn_up, '0');
        end loop;

        --
        -- Down Button
        --

        -- Perform 27 noisy presses and releases.
        for n in 1 to 27 loop
            NoisyTransition(btn_dn, '1');
            NoisyTransition(btn_dn, '0');
        end loop;

        halt_sys_clock <= true;
        wait;
    end process;

    DUT:
    Contador
    generic map
    (
        CLOCK_PERIOD    => CLOCK_PERIOD,
        DEBOUNCE_PERIOD => DEBOUNCE_PERIOD
    )
    port map
    (
        clock  => clock,
        btn_up => btn_up,
        btn_dn => btn_dn,
        x      => x,
        y      => y
    );

end architecture;
```

## Simulation

[image: Simulation of Contador]