# VHDL: [Place 30-574] Poor placement for routing between an IO pin and BUFG

Tags: vhdl, hdl, vivado, vivado-hls

I am trying to design a stopwatch on Nexys4 DDR and get the following error:

```
[Place 30-574] Poor placement for routing between an IO pin and BUFG. If this sub optimal condition is acceptable for this design, you may use the CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE constraint in the .xdc file to demote this message to a WARNING. However, the use of this override is highly discouraged. These examples can be used directly in the .xdc file to override this clock rule.
    < set_property CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE FALSE [get_nets en_IBUF] >

    en_IBUF_inst (IBUF.O) is locked to IOB_X0Y82
     and en_IBUF_BUFG_inst (BUFG.I) is provisionally placed by clockplacer on BUFGCTRL_X0Y1
```

this is my code:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std;


entity cronometru is
     Port (clock: in std_logic;
            directie: in std_logic;
            SW: in std_logic_vector(14 downto 0);
            LED: inout std_logic_vector(14 downto 0);
            en: in std_logic;
            load: in std_logic;
            reset: in std_logic;
            AN: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            afis: out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0));
end cronometru;

architecture crono of cronometru is
signal bcd: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal bcd1: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal bcd2: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal bcd3: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal bcd4: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal bcd5: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal refresh: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
signal temp: std_logic:='1';
signal copiat: std_logic_vector(14 downto 0);
signal zecimal: integer range 0 to 32767;
signal secunde: integer range 0 to 60;
signal zeci_secunde: integer range 0 to 5;
signal unitati_secunde: integer range 0 to 9;
signal minute: integer range 0 to 60;
signal zeci_minute: integer range 0 to 5;
signal unitati_minute: integer range 0 to 9;
signal unitati_ore: integer range 0 to 9;
signal count: std_logic_vector(14 downto 0);
signal enable: std_logic:='0';
begin

process(bcd) --here i display a digit
begin
case bcd is
when "0000" => afis <= "0000001"; -- "0"
when "0001" => afis <= "1001111"; -- "1"
when "0010" => afis <= "0010010"; -- "2"
when "0011" => afis <= "0000110"; -- "3"
when "0100" => afis <= "1001100"; -- "4"
when "0101" => afis <= "0100100"; -- "5"
when "0110" => afis <= "0100000"; -- "6"
when "0111" => afis <= "0001111"; -- "7"
when "1000" => afis <= "0000000"; -- "8"
when "1001" => afis <= "0000100"; -- "9"
when others => afis <= "0110110";
end case;
end process;



process(en) --  here i handle the stop signal 
begin
if (en'event and en='1') then
    enable<=not enable;
end if;
end process;



process(clock)--here i slow down the clock 
variable cnt: integer:=0;
begin
if(clock'event and clock='1') then
    refresh<=refresh+1;
    cnt:=cnt+1;
    if(cnt=50000001)then
        temp<='0';
    end if;
    if(cnt=100000001) then
        temp<='1';
        cnt:=1;
    end if;
end if;
end process;



process(temp, reset, enable,directie,load)
begin
if reset='1' then
    count<=(others=>'0');
elsif load='1' then 
    count<=SW;
elsif (temp='1' and temp'event) then
    if(directie='0' and enable='1') then
        count<=count+1;
    elsif (directie='1' and enable ='1') then 
        count<=count-1;
    else count<=count;
    end if;
end if;
end process;
LED<=count;




process(refresh)
begin --here i find the value of each digit using the number of seconds
copiat<=LED;
zecimal<=conv_integer(unsigned(copiat));
unitati_ore<=zecimal/3600;
minute<=(zecimal mod 3600)/60;
secunde<=(zecimal mod 3600) mod 60;
unitati_minute<=minute mod 10;
zeci_minute<=minute/10;
unitati_secunde<=secunde mod 10;
zeci_secunde<=secunde/10;
bcd1<=conv_std_logic_vector(unitati_secunde,4);
bcd2<=conv_std_logic_vector(zeci_secunde,4);
bcd3<=conv_std_logic_vector(unitati_minute,4);
bcd4<=conv_std_logic_vector(zeci_minute,4);
bcd5<=conv_std_logic_vector(unitati_ore,4);
case refresh is -- here i select what digit to be displayed
when "000"=> AN<="11111110";
            bcd<=bcd1;
when "001"=> AN<="11111101";
            bcd<=bcd2;
when "010"=> AN<="11111011";
            bcd<=bcd3;
when "011"=> AN<="11110111";
             bcd<=bcd4;
when "100"=> AN<="11101111";
             bcd<=bcd5;
when "101"=> AN<="11111011";
             bcd<=bcd3;
when "110"=> AN<="11110111";
             bcd<=bcd4;
when "111"=> AN<="11101111";
             bcd<=bcd5;                                                 
when others => AN<="11111111";
                bcd<="0000";
end case;
end process;
end crono;
```

I can't understand why I'm facing this problem because in my previous implementations I used the clock in exactly same way. Is anybody able to help me?

Here is the code from the constraints file that refer the clock:

```
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN E3    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { clock }]; 
#IO_L12P_T1_MRCC_35 Sch=clock
create_clock -add -name sys_clk_pin -period 10.00 -waveform {0 5} [get_ports {clock}];
```

Comment: 1) Vivado discovered the use you make of signal `clock` and it inferred a clock buffer (`BUFG`) for it. 2) you are trying to use pin `E3` of your FPGA as the primary input for `clock`. 3) This pin is apparently not clock capable and there is no dedicated routing between it and a clock buffer. The tool tells you that this is sub-optimal and can lead to problems. It also tells you that you can force it to proceed anyway, if you wish, with the suggested XDC constraint. The good question, now, is: do you really need this clock to come from pin `E3`?

Comment: @Renaud Pacalet I used their sugestion ```set_property CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE FALSE [get_nets en_IBUF]``` but it didn't work. Also I used the constraints file downloaded from [link]https://reference.digilentinc.com/nexys4-ddr/gsg . I thought that the pin E3 is the right thing to be placed there. I only changed the names of the signals

Comment: Ah, I see, the problem is not `clock`, which is apparently fine (because `E3` **is** clock capable). The problem is `en`, a regular logic input that you try to use as a clock. Why do you try to use it as a clock while you already have a real clock?

Comment: I don't. In this process: 
```process(en) --  here i handle the stop signal 
begin
if (en'event and en='1') then
    enable<=not enable;
end if;
end process;```
I use the signal  ```en```  to stop or start the counting. So, every time I push a button, the local signal  ```enable```  changes its value

Comment: Compare the process `process(en)...` and the following one `process(clock)`. Do you understand that they have exactly the same structure? They do something only on rising edges of a signal, `en` in the first case, `clock` in the second. These two signals are thus used as clocks. Note: Vivado and the other tools usually don't care the names you give to your signals. You can name your reset `clk` and your clock `rst` if you wish (but please don't), it will not influence what the tools do with them. It is the use you make of them that counts, not the names.

Comment: If you want to toggle the `enable` signal each time the `en` signal goes high you need a resynchronizer, an edge detector and maybe a debouncer. All these guys will use `clock` as their clock. `en` will be used as a data input. See [this other question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68562347/how-do-i-correctly-implement-a-finite-state-machine-into-vhdl-without-taking-in) for a starting point on how to do this.

Comment: I see... I didn't know that Vivado treats them in the same way. I thought it only mattered what signals they received. Thanks!